# Como converter ES6 para ES5 no Cordova através de um hook?

Tags: apache-cordova, ecmascript-6

O plugin do crosswalk do Cordova não funciona no iOS, então a WebView do iOS continua a nativa. O problema é que a WebView nativa (safari) não roda ES6, mas o meu projeto está escrito em ES6.

Preciso de uma espécie de hook recursivo que converta todas as partes do meu projeto em ES6 para ES5 a partir do comando `cordova emulate ios`.

**obs1** Sei que há como instalar o Crosswalk manualmente no Cordova para iOS, mas essa alternativa iria quebrar o meu projeto porque essa WebView não é a mesma do Chrome e não conta com certas APIs.

**obs2** Meu projeto não usa módulos do ES6, apenas features mais simples: arrow functions, notações de objeto, template strings etc...

Comment: https://babeljs.io/

Comment: @bfavaretto Gostaria de escrever uma resposta detalhada de como implementar com um hook no Cordova? Eu tenho pouca experiência com ambos.

Comment: Também não tenho conhecimento suficiente para responder